# Error while moving a file into HDFS from Local using Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop

I have a Scala list: fileNames, that contains the file names present on a local directory.
Ex:

```
fileNames(2)
res0: String = file:///tmp/audits/xx_user.log
```

I am trying to move a file from the list: fileNames, from local to HDFS using Scala. In order to do that, I followed the below steps:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
val hadoopconf = new Configuration();
hadoopconf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
val fs = FileSystem.get(hadoopconf);
val outFileStream = fs.create(new Path("hdfs://mydev/user/devusr/testfolder"))
```

The code works fine until here. When I try to add the inputStream, I am getting error message as below:

```
val inStream = fs.open(new Path(fileNames(2)))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file:/tmp/audits/xx_user.log, expected: hdfs://mergedev
```

I also tried by specifying the file name directly and result is same:

```
val inStream = fs.open(new Path("file:///tmp/audits/xx_user.log"))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file:/tmp/audits/xx_user.log, expected: hdfs://mergedev
```

But when I try to load the file directly into spark, it is working fine:

```
val localToSpark = spark.read.text(fileNames(2))
localToSpark: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]
localToSpark.collect
res1: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([[Wed Dec 20 06:18:02 UTC 2017] INFO: ], [*********************************************************************************************************], [ ], [[Wed Dec 20 06:18:02 UTC 2017] INFO: Diagnostic log for xx_user.]
```

Could anyone tell me what is the mistake I am doing at this point: 
`val inStream = fs.open(new Path(fileNames(2)))` for which I am getting the error.

Comment: If you have Spark, why not just write the file to HDFS from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small files, `copyFromLocalFile()` is sufficient:

```
fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path(localFileName), new Path(hdfsFileName))
```

For large files, it's more efficient to use Apache Commons-IO:

```
IOUtils.copyLarge(
  new FileInputStream(new File(localFileName)), fs.create(new Path(hdfsFileName)))
```

Keep in mind that the local file name should **not** include the protocol (so no `file:///` in there)